# Group by + rolling mean in Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I need to translate this piece of pandas code:

```
df.groupby(groupby_col)[[A_col, B_col]].rolling(window=window, on=B_col, closed = 'left').agg(some_function)
```

to polars.

*A_col* features Int64 dtype, *B_col* datetime (ns).

I came up with the following formulation:

```
df.group_by(groupby_col).agg(pl.col([A_col, B_col])).with_columns(
pl.col([A_col, B_col]).rolling_mean(window_size=30,  by=B_col, closed="left"))
```

leading me to this error:

```
`expr_name` operation not supported for dtype `list[date]` (expected: date/datetime)
```

I cannot understand why it cannot take a list of dates as "by" for the rolling mean.

Comment: in pandas you use `by=B_col` and you state that `B_col` is of type `datetime`. On the other hand in polar you use `by=price_col` instead of `date_col`. Is that an overlook?

Comment: Please give example input of df

Comment: Can you please add an actual runnable code example? The answer below (with respect to the submitter) is not the recommended way to do things in Polars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def custom_rolling_function(group_df):
    return group_df.select([
        pl.col(price_col).rolling_mean(window_size=30).alias('rolling_mean_price'),
        pl.col(date_col)
    ])

result = df.groupby(groupby_col).apply(custom_rolling_function)
```

This should get updated in new column "rolling_mean_price". This does for translation part.