# Polars filter dataframe with multilple conditions

Tags: python, python-polars

I've got this pandas code:

```
df['date_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
row['date_col'] = pd.to_datetime(row['date_col'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

df = df[(df['groupby_col'] == row['groupby_col']) & 
        (row['date_col'] - df['date_col'] <= timedelta(days = 10)) & 
        (row['date_col'] - df['date_col'] > timedelta(days = 0))]

row['mean_col]' = df['price_col'].mean()
```

The name `row` comes from the fact that this function was applied by a lambda construct.

I'm subsetting df with 2 types of conditions:

- 1. A condition on values equality on a column named "groupby_col",
- 2. Multiple onditions on time ranges based on the "date_col" column that features timestamps.

I'm pretty sure that `filter` is the correct module to use:

```
df.filter(condition_1 & condition_2)
```

but i'm struggling to write the conditions.
In order to embed condition 1 do i have to nest a filter condition or a `when` is the correct choice?
How do i translate the `timedelta` condition?
How do i replicate the lambda approach?

Comment: it would've been nice to have some example input and output though

Comment: At this point, you are unfortunately "littering" the Polars tag by repeatedly ignoring requests for runnable code examples in your questions. This is leading to sub-optimal answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77861609/ which devalues the whole process from a learning perspective. Plenty of people want to help if you can please put in the effort.

Comment: @jqurious Agree. Thanks for making me aware of the other questions of similar style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hard to understand your example without test data.
But if I try to create some sample data

```
import polars as pl
import datetime

df = pl.DataFrame({
   "date_col": ['2023-01-01','2023-01-02', '2023-01-03'],
   "groupby_col": [1,2,3],
})

row = pl.DataFrame({
   "date_col": ['2023-01-07','2023-01-08', '2023-01-25'],
   "groupby_col": [1,2,3],
})

df = df.with_columns(pl.col('date_col').str.to_datetime().cast(pl.Date))
row = row.with_columns(pl.col('date_col').str.to_datetime().cast(pl.Date))
```

then you can filter on multiple conditions by joining two dataframes first and then filtering:

```
(df
   .join(row, on=["groupby_col"])
   .filter(
       pl.col("date_col_right") - pl.col("date_col") >= datetime.timedelta(days=0),
       pl.col("date_col_right") - pl.col("date_col") < datetime.timedelta(days=10),
   ).drop('date_col_right')
)

shape: (2, 2)
┌────────────┬─────────────┐
│ date_col   ┆ groupby_col │
│ ---        ┆ ---         │
│ date       ┆ i64         │
╞════════════╪═════════════╡
│ 2023-01-01 ┆ 1           │
│ 2023-01-02 ┆ 2           │
└────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Answer (score 4):

We start with some example data.

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta

import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "group": ["A"] * 3 + ["B"] * 3,
    "date": [date(2023, month, 1) for month in range(1, 7)]
})
```

The dataframe looks as follows.

```
shape: (6, 2)
┌───────┬────────────┐
│ group ┆ date       │
│ ---   ┆ ---        │
│ str   ┆ date       │
╞═══════╪════════════╡
│ A     ┆ 2023-01-01 │
│ A     ┆ 2023-02-01 │
│ A     ┆ 2023-03-01 │
│ B     ┆ 2023-04-01 │
│ B     ┆ 2023-05-01 │
│ B     ┆ 2023-06-01 │
└───────┴────────────┘
```

We can then filter the dataframe using a filter on the `group` column and multiple filters on the `date` column. Note how the predicates in the [`pl.DataFrame.filter`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.filter.html) context are implicitly joined using `&`.

```py
(
    df
    .filter(
        pl.col("group") == "A",
        pl.col("date") - date(2023, 1, 1) >= timedelta(days=5),
        pl.col("date") - date(2023, 1, 1) <= timedelta(days=50),
    )
)
```

**Output.**

```
shape: (1, 2)
┌───────┬────────────┐
│ group ┆ date       │
│ ---   ┆ ---        │
│ str   ┆ date       │
╞═══════╪════════════╡
│ A     ┆ 2023-02-01 │
└───────┴────────────┘
```

Comment: This answer disregards the "lambda approach" mentioned in the question and is based on the title of your question. It might make sense to elaborate the lambda/`apply` part in more detail in a new question.